# VBA Changing name of all files in a folder

Tags: vba

In a folder I have some images named 1;2;3;4;5;6 for example and I need to change the name of each one like this :

1 become 6 /
2 become 5 /
3 become 4 
... etc

This example work with 6 images but i can have many more.

I start some work for looping throught all files in a directory

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
Dim StrFile As String
StrFile = Dir("c:\xxx\*test*")
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    Debug.Print StrFile
    StrFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

I may need to copy them in an another folder because I can't name a file 6 if there is already one ?

Thank's for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rename file "1" to "6" if the "6" is still there, so we need to first rename each file to a temporary name. For this reason we loop all files in the folder twice. Note that the files must be named numbers only (plus extension), or the code will fail. Back-up your images before running the script.

```
Public Sub rename_all_files_in_folder(folderPath As String)

'''   for this code to work, Microsoft Scripting Runtime reference is required (Tools -> References)
Const temp_filename_prefix As String = "to_be_renamed_"
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim f As Scripting.file
Dim fileCount As Integer
Dim newFilename As String
Dim extension As String

Set fso = New FileSystemObject

fileCount = 0
If fso.FolderExists(folderPath) Then

    '''   first cycle, each file gets temporary name
    For Each f In fso.GetFolder(folderPath).Files
        fileCount = fileCount + 1
        'fso.FindFileInFolder = f.Name
        f.Name = temp_filename_prefix & f.Name
    Next f

    '''   second cycle to rename from temporary name to new name
    For Each f In fso.GetFolder(folderPath).Files
        extension = "." & fso.GetExtensionName(f.path)
        newFilename = CStr(fileCount + 1 - CInt(Replace(Replace(f.Name, temp_filename_prefix, ""), extension, ""))) & extension
        f.Name = newFilename
    Next f
Else
    MsgBox "Folder not found:" & vbCrLf & folderPath
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use this:

```
Public Sub SwapFiles()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim fileCount As Long

    folderPath = "c:\xxx" ' folder path to search files into

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        For fileCount = 1 To 3
            .CopyFile folderPath & "\" & fileCount & ".jpg", folderPath & "\" & "temp.jpg"
            .CopyFile folderPath & "\" & (6 - fileCount + 1) & ".jpg", folderPath & "\" & fileCount & ".jpg"
            .CopyFile folderPath & "\" & "temp.jpg", folderPath & "\" & (6 - fileCount + 1) & ".jpg"
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

just change "jpg" to your actual image files extension